# Obtener el estatus de una impresora en tiempo real C#

Tags: c#

Tengo problemas al obtener la información de estatus, el código es el siguiente:

```
//Pruebas de estatus
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct PRINTER_INFO_2
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This member MUST be a non-NULL pointer to a string that MUST specify the name of the server that hosts the printer. For rules governing server names, see section 2.2.4.16.
        /// summary>
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
        public string pServerName;
        /// <summary>
        /// This member MUST be a non-NULL pointer to a string that MUST specify the name of a printer. For rules governing printer names, see section 2.2.4.14.
        /// summary>
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
        public string pPrinterName;
        /// <summary>
        /// This member is an optional pointer to a string that specifies the share name for the printer. This string MUST be ignored unless the Attributes member contains the PRINTER_ATTRIBUTED_SHARED flag. For rules governing path names, see section 2.2.4.9.
        /// summary>
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
        public string pShareName;
        /// <summary>
        /// This member is a pointer to a string that specifies the port(s) used to transmit data to a printer. For rules governing port names, see section 2.2.4.10.
        /// summary>
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
        public string pPortName;
        /// <summary>
        ///  This member is a pointer to a string that specifies the name of the printer driver. For rules governing printer driver names, see section 2.2.4.3.
        /// summary>
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
        public string pDriverName;
        /// <summary>
        ///  This member is an optional pointer to a string that MUST specify additional information about the printer.<18>
        /// summary>
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
        public string pComment;
        /// <summary>
        /// This member is an optional pointer to a string that specifies the location of the printer.
        /// summary>
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
        public string pLocation;
        /// <summary>
        /// This member is an optional pointer to a truncated DEVMODE structure (section 2.2.1.1.1), and MUST be ignored on receipt. Actual DEVMODE data is passed to a method via a custom-marshaled _DEVMODE structure (section 2.2.2.1) in a DEVMODE_CONTAINER (section 2.2.1.2.1).
        /// summary>
        public IntPtr pDevMode;
        /// <summary>
        ///  This member is an optional pointer to a string that specifies the name of a file whose contents are used to create a separator page. This page is used to separate print jobs sent to the printer. For rules governing path names, see section 2.2.4.9.
        /// summary>
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
        public string pSepFile;
        /// <summary>
        /// This member is an optional pointer to a string that specifies the name of the print processor used by the printer. For rules governing print processor names, see section 2.2.4.11.
        /// summary>
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
        public string pPrintProcessor;
        /// <summary>
        /// This member is an optional pointer to a string that specifies the default data format used to record print jobs on the printer. For rules governing data type names, see section 2.2.4.2.
        /// summary>
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
        public string pDatatype;
        /// <summary>
        /// his member is an optional pointer to a string that specifies the default print processor parameters.
        /// summary>
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
        public string pParameters;
        /// <summary>
        /// This member is an optional pointer to a SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR structure ([MS-DTYP] section 2.4.6), and MUST be ignored on receipt. Actual SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR data is passed to a method via a self-relative SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR structure in a SECURITY_CONTAINER (section 2.2.1.2.13).
        /// summary>
        public IntPtr pSecurityDescriptor;

        public uint Attributes;
        /// <summary>
        ///  The value of this member specifies a priority value that the spooler uses to route each print job. The value of this member MUST be from 0 through 99, inclusive.
        /// summary>
        public uint Priority;
        /// <summary>
        /// The value of this member specifies the default priority value assigned to each print job. The value of this member MUST be from 0 through 99, inclusive.
        /// summary>
        public uint DefaultPriority;
        /// <summary>
        /// The value of this member specifies the earliest time that a job can be printed. The time is expressed as the number of minutes after 12:00 AM GMT within a 24-hour boundary.
        /// summary>
        public uint StartTime;
        /// <summary>
        /// The value of this member specifies the latest time that a job can be printed. The time is expressed as the number of minutes after 12:00 AM GMT within a 24-hour boundary
        /// summary>
        public uint UntilTime;
        /// <summary>
        /// This member specifies the printer status. It is the result of a bitwise OR of zero or more printer status values (section 2.2.3.12).
        /// summary>
        public uint Status;
        /// <summary>
        ///  The value of this member specifies the number of print jobs that have been queued for the printer
        /// summary>
        public uint cJobs;
        /// <summary>
        ///  The value of this member specifies the average pages per minute that have been printed on the printer.
        /// summary>
        public uint AveragePPM;
    }

    /// <param name="printerName">param>
    /// <returns>returns>
    public static PRINTER_INFO_2? GetPrinterInfo(String printerName)
    {
        IntPtr pHandle;
        WSDos.PRINTER_DEFAULTS defaults = new WSDos.PRINTER_DEFAULTS();
        PRINTER_INFO_2? Info2 = null;

        WSDos.OpenPrinter(printerName, out pHandle, ref defaults);

        Int32 cbNeeded = 0;

        bool bRet = WSDos.GetPrinter(pHandle, 2, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out cbNeeded);

        if (cbNeeded > 0)
        {
            IntPtr pAddr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)cbNeeded);

            bRet = WSDos.GetPrinter(pHandle, 2, pAddr, cbNeeded, out cbNeeded);

            if (bRet)
            {
                Info2 = (PRINTER_INFO_2)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pAddr, typeof(PRINTER_INFO_2));
            }

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pAddr);
        }

        WSDos.ClosePrinter(pHandle);

        return Info2;
    }
```

Como ven utilizo el método GetPrinter asignando el tipo de estructura numero 2. Supuestamente con esto se obtienen mas detalle acerca del dispositivo y en efecto me trae el estatus pero no es el correspondiente porque hago pruebas quitandole el rollo de papel o incluso hasta desconectandola pero casi siempre obtengo un 0 que significa que esta en buen estado y no es asi. Solo cuando apago la impresora o reinicio la aplicación que estoy haciendo devuelve el valor correcto y así se queda.¿Existe alguna otra manera para que la impresora lance la el estatus real?

Answer (score 1):

El tema es que no estas generando ningun evento que recibas cuando cambia de estado, por eso sino vuelves a ejecutar la accion no se actualiza.

Sino tienes evento podrias invocar a `GetPrinterInfo()` dentro de un `Timer`, no se cada 30seg validar el estado de la impresora

```
public void Timer1_Tick(...){

   var result = GetPrinterInfo("nombre impresora");

   //aqui actualizas controles con la nueva informacion

}
```

Tambien se podrias lograr aplicando `WMI`, este cuanta con el `ManagementEventWatcher` para generar el evento, pero basicamente tambien se le define un intervalo de tiempo en el cual valida y lanza la accion en un evento, quizas queda algo mejor que usar un timer, pero el resultado final seria el mismo

[WMI management event watcher](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/135795-wmi-management-event-watcher/)

En el ejemplo define una query de WMI para validar el puerto usb, pero para impresion solo cambiaria la query

[About the state of printers](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d3b90e1f-93bf-41d6-975a-06d6be7149ac/about-the-state-of-printers?forum=netfxbcl)

algo como ser

```
WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery();
query.EventClassName = "_InstanceOperationEvent";
query.WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
query.Condition = @"TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Printer'";

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2");

ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, query);
watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(PrintHandler);
```

entonces adjuntas el evento

```
public void PrintHandler(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (PropertyData pd in e.NewEvent.Properties)
    {
        //codigo
    }

}
```